# Основные навыки фронтенд-разработчика?

Tags: веб-программирование, frontend

Очень многие начинающие фронтенд-разработчики часто задают вопросы на эту тему. Что нужно знать чтобы чтобы состояться в этой профессии? Что именно нужно учить? Как вообще ориентироваться в гигантском объеме информации о фронтенде?

Comment: Похвально, что вы решили поделиться своими знаниями, но подобные вопросы на СО являются оффтопиком как слишком обширные (или как "опросники"). Проблема в том, что ответы на подобные вопросы очень быстро теряют актуальность, и никто не поддерживает их. Кроме того, они слишком открыты для споров: одни считают одно важным, другие — другое. СО в первую очередь предназначен для вопросов, которые имеют конкретные ответы, которые не устареют через полгода.

Comment: @Discord а с литературой таких проблем нет? Есть ведь общие вопросы по ним. Хотя тут, конечно, более нестабильная тема.

Comment: @Regent Литература — это отдельно взятое исключение (на большом СО она вынесена в вики меток). Вопросы по литературе общие и реально поддерживаются. Кроме того, литература актуальна достаточно долго. Если завтра выйдет C# 7, литература по C# 6 всё ещё будет актуальной.

Comment: @Discord, очень уж часто задают этот вопрос. И в личку спрашивают. Даже если вопрос немного оффтопик, приятнее хранить ответ на него здесь, на СО.

Comment: @IonDen Вопрос не "немного оффтопик", он "совсем оффтопик". Мне, например, было бы удобно хранить рецепт яблочного пирога на СО, но я же этого не делаю. Ваш вопрос, если его оставить, через полгода станет бесполезным, то есть через полгода он будет *вреден*.

Comment: @Discord, принцип понятен. Хотя, имхо, ответ на этот вопрос вполне проживёт еще пару лет.

Comment: @IonDen он проживет, но ответ на него практически бесполезен. Он просто перечисляет технологии и фреймворки. 30 штук. Для тех, кто ориентируется в стеке - он не нужен. Для новичков - тем более - им список из 30 названий не говорит ни о чем.

Comment: @IonDen, а Вы молодец. Я, конечно, совсем не в теме фронтенда (да и, пожалуй, вообще веб-разработок), но прочел с интересом. Жаль прикрыли, может спросил бы Вас о, скажем так, *логических транзакциях* (проблемах согласованности данных) в фронт- (и -бэк?) -енде.

Comment: @avp, сформулируйте новый вопрос тут, на СО. Я уверен что многим будет что сказать на эту тему.

Comment: Лучше переквалифицироваться в управдомы, чем обладать всеми этими навыками фронтенд. Пока не сделают что-нибудь действительно годное со всем этим фронтедом на фундаментальном уровне

Comment: @banme, да во фронтенде пока полный швах)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Попробую немного структурировать:

- База: **EcmaScript 5**, **HTML(5)** и **CSS(3)** - надо знать обязательно.
- Будущее: **EcmaScript 2015+**, **HTML5+** и **CSS3(4)+** - надо знать.
- Популярные расширения JS: **EcmaScript 2015+ через Babel**, **TypeScript** и т.д. - EcmaScript через Babel предпочтительнее всего, так как позволяет уже сегодня использовать будущее JS.
- Расширения HTML: **Haml**, **Jade** и т.д. можно попробовать, если нравится синтаксис, но можно и обойтись.
- Популярные расширения CSS: **LESS/SASS/Stylus** и т.д. - обязательно что-то выбрать, изучать и использовать в работе.
- Известные JS-фреймворки и библиотеки: SPA-фремворки/библиотеки (**Vue.js, React.js, Angular** и т.д.) - обязательно начать что-то изучать и использовать. Весь современный веб строится на этом, сайты всё больше превращаются в приложения. **jQuery** - можно забывать.
- Известные CSS-фреймворки: **Bootstrap**, **Foundation** и т.д. - могут пригодиться, особенно Bootstrap с его множеством полезных модулей.
- Системы сборки: **Webpack/Grunt/Gulp** и т.д. обязательно нужно начать изучать и использовать. Без этого сейчас никуда.
- Там где сборка там же и **Node.js**, командная строка и репозитории вроде **Yarn, **NPM**, тоже полезно изучать для управления зависимостями проекта.**

Дополнительно:

- Всегда стоит помнить о работе в команде (даже если вы сейчас работаете один): это система контроля версий **Git** и платформы GitHub/Bitbucket - я рекомендую каждый свой проект хранить там. Очень удобно.
- Так же, во время работы/учебы вы обязательно коснётесь этих вопросов: оптимизация, алогоритмы, сетевые протоколы, особенности работы браузеров и т.д., очень важно знать, как всё работает изнутри.
- Для общего развития та же полезно изучать еще какой-то язык программирования, помимо JS

Как видите, требования для современного фронтенд-разработчика невероятно обширны, технологический бум продолжается. Так что, надеюсь, моя заметка поможет вам лучше ориентироваться.

Comment: Никакого отношения к вопросу GitHub не имеет. Не надо валить все в одну кучу.