# как изучать программирование? (принципы, техники, методики)

Tags: любой-язык

Книги, статьи о том "как изучать программирование" ?  Методы, техники, принципы.. Что-нибудь подскажите пожалуйста )

П.С. Модерация посчитала вопрос очень абстрактным и обширным. Так и есть. Суть в поиске общих методик и практик для изучения.  Языки программирования похожи (циклы, переменные, буквенно-цифровые обозначения  и  т.п. ) поэтому подход к изучению будет одинаков.  Поэтому сделать вопрос более конкретным я не могу. Для себя нашел авторов такие как Скотт Янг и Николай Ягодкин ( эти авторы рассказывают о том как изучать технические, математические науки с высоким уровнем абстракции. Техники применимы и для программирования. Если кого заинтересует, гуглите.

Comment: Ответ можно найти поиском например тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459646/%d0%9e%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b4-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Основные навыки фронтенд-разработчика?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459646/%d0%9e%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b4-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: Вы изменили вопрос не в лучшую сторону) он стал ещё более обширным

Comment: Как раз-таки сложные алгоритмы вам вряд ли понадобятся. Максимум - какие-нибудь сложные модификации объектов. Изучайте углубленно какой-нибудь из современных фреймворков: нативщики практически нигде не нужны. Базы данных - базовый уровень, чтоб было понимание. Дизайн изучайте. Верстка. Протокол HTTP желательно бы знать на базовом уровне. Способы, методы и принципы взаимодействия с бекендом. Английский - критично.

Answer (score 1):

Есть отличная [статья](https://proglib.io/p/react-developer-2019/), там целая карта для развития. Я с ней согласен.

Я собрал [файл](https://docs.google.com/document/d/11bEOijLSGTu99iWID0901tmuK53L6fS3HFQvaZ6RGI8/edit?usp=sharing) на что стоит посмотреть

Comment: Я считаю, было не плохо, если перенести с "файлика" в ответ

Comment: у меня не достаточно баллов репутации, чтобы столько ссылок добавить в ответ